# Why env variable is not overwriting the spring's configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, spring-boot-configuration

I have a spring-boot application with a `ConfigurationProperties` class. I am deploying the app with helm + kubernetes so passing the env variables to overwrite the config values. But somehow, some variables are not overwritten by this env variables and I cannot see why. The config class looks like:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("abc-config")
data class AbcConfiguration(
    private var authorizationConfigs: List<TokenGrantConfiguration> = listOf(),
) {}

class TokenGrantConfiguration(
    clientId: String,
    clientSecret: String,
)
```

And my env variables are like:

```
ABC_CONFIG_AUTHORIZATION_CONFIGS_0_CLIENT_ID="some_client_id"
ABC_CONFIG_AUTHORIZATION_CONFIGS_0_CLIENT_SECRET="some_client_secret"
```

Just to add, my app also has the `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` variable as :

```
{
    abc-config: {
      "authorization-configs": [
        {
          "clientId": "",
          "clientSecret": ""
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

So when I run the app, the clientId and secret values are both empty, not overwritten by the env variables. I have also checked with `System.env("...")` to check if the env variables are set right and they seem are right.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [rules for mapping environment variable names to Spring properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables) are:

> - Replace dots (.) with underscores (_).
> - Remove any dashes (-).
> - Convert to uppercase.

If your property names are hyphenated or camel-cased, the environment variable name does *not* have an extra underscore between the human-readable words; they are just mashed together.

In your code, the name `abc-config` would map to an environment-variable component `ABCCONFIG`, the property `clientId` to `CLIENTID`, and so on.  The environment variable name I'd expect to work is

```bash
ABCCONFIG_AUTHORIZATIONCONFIGS_0_CLIENTID="some_client_id"
```